# Cleartool - How to apply label to objects' latest versions created before a specific time?

Tags: date, find, label, clearcase, cleartool

I want to apply a label to latest versions of objects that created before a specific time. For example :

`MyObject.java` has 4 versions.
 - 1. version created on 2010-01-02
 - 2. version created on 2010-06-25
 - 3. version created on **2013-03-17**
 - 4. version created on 2014-01-13

Let's say I have 100+ objects in a specific path.

I want to find versions of objects created before `2014-01-01` and apply label to latest versions that obtain this condition of all objects (elements).

In this example;
I want to apply label on `MyObject.java@@\main\3`

Thanks

**Update :** 
I am looking for a command like this :

```
find . -version "created_since(01-Jan-2000) && !created_since(01-Jan-2014) &&  version(/main/LATEST)" -print -exec "mklabel -replace TO_PROD"
```

this one is not working! I think it wants full path of objects. This find command returns paths that not include VOB path.

Answer (score 1):

Finding version *before* a time is tricky.

Finding version *after* a time is easier (`created_since`).

The [OP akdora](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3187233/akdora) mentions:

```
find . -version "created_since(01-Jan-2000) && !created_since(01-Jan-2014) &&  version(/main/LATEST)" -print -exec "mklabel -replace TO_PROD"
```

That is:

```
find . -version "created_since(01-Jan-2000) && 
                 !created_since(01-Jan-2014) &&  
                 version(/main/LATEST)" 
       -print 
       -exec "mklabel -replace TO_PROD"
```

It should work if you add in the `exec` directive the right [`cleartool mklabel`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_mklabel.htm) syntax:

```
-exec "cleartool mklabel -replace TO_PROD \"%CLEARCASE_PN%\""
```

(Windows syntax)

The `CLEARCASE_PN` environment variable is set automatically by the `cleartool find` command, and reference each element (not version) found.

```
find . -version "created_since(01-Jan-2000) && 
                 !created_since(01-Jan-2014)"
       -print 
       -exec "cleartool mklabel -replace TO_PROD \"%CLEARCASE_PN%\""
```

---

Alternative method

The "[Additional examples of the `cleartool find` command](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21124425)" document includes:

#### Find and label all element versions before a certain date and time:

> Get all the files in a VOB and store that data in a flat file:

```
cleartool find <vobtag> -all -print > <filename1>
```

> or

```
cleartool find <vobtag> -version -print > <filename>
```

> Get all the files created after the target date/time and store that data in a flat file:

```
cleartool find <vobtag> -element "{created_since(target-data-time)}" -print >
```

> or

```
cleartool find <vobtag> -version "{created_since(target-data-time)}" -print >
```

> Compare the two files to get the 'before version set'.
>
> Do this by taking the first entry in `filename2`, then going to `filename1` and taking everything that occurs before that line in `filename1`:
>
> - Save that in a new file, `<filename3>`
> - For every entry in `<filename3>` execute:

```
    cleartool mklabel <labelname>
```

Comment: Actually i was looking for somthing like a command that i updated post

Comment: I checked it again. **"created_since(01-Jan-2000) && !created_since(01-Jan-2014) &&  version(/main/LATEST)"** is NOT working :( Sorry..  This finds if the latest version is created before 01-Jan-2014 then, prints the object.

Comment: @akdora right: you don't need the `&& version(/main/LATEST)` part. If it finds version from the oldest to the newest, the last `mklabel` will be applied to the right version (the most recent one before a specific date).